# Parallel queries against database

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, multithreading, task-parallel-library

For instance, let's say I have the following pseudo code:

```
InsertSomethingToDb1();
InsertSomethingToDb2();
InsertSomethingToDb3();
InsertSomethingToDb4();
```

Then one Insert operation takes `DbTripTime + InsertTime + DbTripTime`.
So for 4 operations it will take `4 * (DbTripTime + InsertTime + DbTripTime)` to finish.

My question is will this be faster if those inserts are done in parallel? Would time than be `DbTripTime +  4 * InsertTime + DbTripTime`? And if it is faster how much does it depend on number of CPU cores?

Comment: Doing async IO doesn't depend on cores at all. It primarily depends on how many IOPS the machine the database is stored on can do, and depends on the design of the DB Schema. If one of those queries has to lock the table, and another has to insert, then you won't really enjoy the benefits of concurrency.

Comment: We do not know your environment, workload, database- storage-design, locking and so on. You would get an answer if you test it.

Comment: Lets assume they all target different tables, I just want to know would doing each insert in a separate thread give some benefit in performance?

Comment: I don't intend to use it now, it is just a teoretical question...

Comment: For really fast inserts you can usually use the SqlBulkCopy class, but as allready stated it's hard to give an answer that matches all possible environments. That said I have gotten things a lot faster by having multiple threads on a client do sql against the same server.

Comment: It's the wrong question, based on the incorrect assumption that somehow a single connection uses a single core. Performance will most likely degrade *seriously* unless you are *very* careful. Multiple threads trying to access the same IO resources result in more locks, blocking and delays.

Comment: Using concurrent bulk import operations can only result in speed increases if each connection targets a *different* spindle. Eg, if you partition your table and store each partition to a different disk (array, spindle etc), you could use separate connections to import data that will end up in different partitions

Comment: Which answers your last question as well - it has nothing at all to do with the number of cores. Storing data is IO-intensive, so what matters is the number of disks, not CPUs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But its not just IO operation that is problem, it is also the database trip time. If we send requests one by one then we have 4 * 2 database trips, right?

Comment: No, because you *should not* send requests one by one. Send them as a single batch. This is supported by .NET and most ORMs. You can also use SqlBulkCopy to send the data as a stream using minimal logging. If you really have a lot of data to send though, export it from the initial source to a file (using whatever bulk export mechanism is available), move the file to a local disk on the server, then do a bulk insert

Comment: anything pertain to performance, especially using custom feature, it's best u test and measure it. theory is just theory